# C Unit Test Framework that compare arrays

Tags: c, arrays, unit-testing

I'm looking for a C Unit Test Framework that has a native function (or macro) to compare arrays. I already took a look in [cut](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cut/), [check](http://check.sourceforge.net/), [CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html), [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/) and [MinUnit](https://github.com/siu/minunit) but can't find it.

Since I will use it for some scientific computation, as a [MWE](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Minimal-Working-Example-%28MWE%29.html) it needs to be capable of testing a function like:

```
// compute x = a + b
void fsum(int n, float *a, float *b, float *x){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x[i] = a[i] + b[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not write one? And then put it out for all us to enjoy>

Comment: What would you expect the hypothetical array comparator to do to check the code you show?  Or are you looking for a framework that can help you set up 2 arrays (`a` and `b`) and then let you validate that `x` contains the same values as another array (call it `c`) that contains precomputed values for the sum of each entry in `a` and `b`?

Comment: Jonathan, some similar to what you say: "looking for a framework that can help you set up 2 arrays (`a` and `b`) and then let you validate that `x` contains the same values as another array (call it `c`) that contains precomputed values for the sum of each entry in `a` and `b`".

Answer (score 0):

[cmocka](http://cmocka.org/) has assert functions for sets, see [assert_in_set()](http://api.cmocka.org/group__cmocka__asserts.html#gaae80374c5107fd81f0c38b2495452ffe)